# Is it possible to change the RESX generator to use public accessor on generated class?

Tags: .net

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC application and trying to use a RESX file to store error messages and other common strings.  The problem is that the RESX generator builds internal classes and it's not possible to use them in the ASP.NET HTML code using a syntax like:

```
<%= Resources.SomeString %>
```

Is it possible to tweak a setting to get the RESX generator to build a publicly accessible class and properties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The access modifier can be set to `Public` from a combo-box at the top menu of the resource editor.

http://docs.google.com/File?id=dcfqfqs2_2gfcb5ndc_b