# DisplayAttribute: No good for resources in App_GlobalResources

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization

This question applies to all projects really, however my demonstrating environment is an MVC3 app, hence that tag.

I wrote a `DisplayNameAttribute`-derived class for our MVC2 projects, like so many people have, so I could localise display names in MVC editors and display templates.  I lifted the `ValidationAttribute` localisation code used for the error message so that it behaved in a 'standard' way.

Then I noticed that in MVC3 we have the `DisplayAttribute`, so I dutifully obsoleted my attribute class in the .Net 4 version of my MVC extension framework and changed the model properties in my current project to use this, e.g:

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.MyResources), Name = "ResourceName")]
public string ModelProperty { get; set; }
```

Then I run the web app and I get an error similar to this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed.  Type '[Resource Type Here]' is not public or does not contain a public static string property with the name '[Resource Name Here]'.

I use localisation in various places of course, and in class libraries such resources will be typically be marked public.  In web applications, however, I will use the `App_GlobalResources` folder because, well, *that's what it's for!*

The problem here is that the resource accessors that are generated for resx files in this folder are **always** generated as internal access, with no way of changing it.

So, since `DisplayAttribute` seems only to look for public members (whereas the localisation code I copied from `ValidationAttribute` and applied to my own `DisplayNameAttribute`-deriving type simply looks for static members with either public OR internal visibility), it would appear that `DisplayAttribute` is off-limits to any MVC web apps that intend to use `App_GlobalResources` for the localised strings?

Apart from the fact that this is *probably* a bug in `DisplayAttribute`, has anybody else hit this problem?  What did you do to solve it?  Should I honour the usage of `DisplayAttribute` and change all my resources to be 'properly' embedded as in the class library projects, and set them all as public?  Or should I ditch DisplayAttribute in favour of my other class that I know works!?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<strike>You should be able to change the access modifier. In Solution Explorer, double-click your .resx file, then near the top-right of the managed resource editor, change the *Access Modifier* drop-down from `Internal` to `Public`.</strike>

**Update**

This might work: [Making global resources public](http://holyhoehle.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/making-global-resources-public/)

Comment: Nevermind my answer. I just noticed the drop-down is enabled just for local resources, not global ones. My apologies.

Comment: Oh yeah, absolutely. I have no idea why they force global resources to be internal.

Comment: +1 & answer - I haven't done this in the end, I just went back to my own attribute, which worked.  However this is probably the easiest way if using `DisplayAttribute` is absolutely required.

Answer (score 3):

[This post](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx) explains a bit more about the issues with using App_GlobalResources or App_Localresources in MVC applications.

It seems there is no reason to use App_GlobalResources or App_Localresources in MVC applications, and it's better not to use them to avoid problems like the one you are experiencing. (Another problem you can run into, according to the previous link, is failing unit tests. This is because the resources are only available when the ASP.NET runtime is running your website)

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to generate as **public** see [more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275257/is-it-possible-to-change-the-resx-generator-to-use-public-accessor-on-generated-c)

Comment: no you can't - you can do this on 'normal' resx files that are compiled as embedded resources; but you cannot do this on Asp.Net App_GlobalResource resource files.  For some very odd reason they are fixed at internal and you also cannot change the namespace they are compiled into.